# Presence of Aromatase enzyme in males : Result of Natural Selection

Tags: enzymes, protein-evolution

Males have increased chances of getting cardiovascular diseases than females ; one of the reasons might be less level of oestrogen ( which decreases deposition of low density lipoprotein **LDL** in blood vessels).

I know that Aromatase enzyme is produced by sertoli cells in males. It converts androgen into oestrogen.

Now ,
today my teacher said that the presence of Aromatase enzyme in males is the result of natural selection against increased chances of heart attack in males.

My question is-

**1.** Is the amount of oestrogen produced significant to decrease cardiovascular diseases that it can lead to natural selection?

**2.** Are there any evidences for the same? please enlist them.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estrogen has other functions in males; it is very misleading to attribute the ability in males to synthesize estrogen to effects on heart attack chances. The relationship between estrogen and cardiovascular disease risk is also very complicated, and current guidelines do [not suggest estrogen replacement as a preventative treatment for heart disease](https://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/educational/hearttruth/lower-risk/hormone-therapy.htm).

A better explanation for increased male risk of heart attack might be the increased levels of testosterone, but the data on that are mixed as well.

Comment: Thanks ! The link you provided was helpful. So basically, it plays role in maturation of sperm?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrogen#Function) has a list of functions of estrogen - many of these are not specific to females. On your own, you could also research the effects on males who have a deficiency in aromatase.